# Terminal Commands in Manjaro (Arch operating system) to Push Github project

Tags: linux, github, terminal, push, arch

After changing from **linux** to *arch* **linux** so make cmds get changed so....in linux I know how to push ...but in **arch** **linux** ....no idea

Comment: Are you using git command line client? I don't use Manjaro but in Arch, the client can be installed using `pacman`. Moreover, the commands would be same as in other Linux distros such as Debian, Ubuntu and even Windows and MacOS. Also, *"After changing from linux to arch linux"* is very much vague since Linux itself is actually a kernel and on that many distros are based. So, I'm not sure which *distro* you used previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have installed git, and as long as I'm concerned I think it is preinstalled in Manjaro.

The steps you have to take are exactly the same as in any OS because the commands are Git dependent, not OS dependent.

In this case you should `git init` the directory you want to make a repo, then `git add .` for adding all of the files to the repo and then `git commit . -m "message"` to commit the changes.

After all this you need to go to your GitHub repository and copy the command to push the project there, the command will be something like this

`git remote add origin https://github.com/rubendario99/manjaroTest.git`

and last but not least `git push -u origin master`